# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save' [Flask FIle Upload]

Tags: python, html, flask

```
@app.route('/form')
def form():
    return render_template('form.html')


@app.route("/upload", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.form.get('file')
        full_filename = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'resume1')
        f.save(full_filename)



        return ("Uploaded Successfully")
```

form.html

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "/upload" method = "post" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name = "file" />
         <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to upload a file using flask but it is throwing me this error
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the uploaded file using this line `f = request.form.get('file')`. You need to replace that line with this.

```
f = request.files.get("file")
```

Comment: This also doesnt work